# How to Copy Data to a new Spreadsheet then save as a PDF?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google script that copies a range of values to a new spreadsheet and then sets that new copy as a pdf then emails it. Everything works but the values are set after the pdf is created. So I get an email with a blank pdf. I tried using the "Utilities.sleep()" but that did not work either. Any clue why the values get copied after the pdf is made?

If you need clarification on the code let me know.

```
function myFunction() {
  //Template Info
  var sheetTemplate = ""; //sheet id goes here

  //Sheet with List of Suppliers
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var info = sheet.getRange("A1:B1").getValues();

  //Grabs name and email
  var name = "";
  name = info[0][0];
  var email = "";
  email = info[0][1];

  //Copies template and save the sheet's id
  var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(sheetTemplate).makeCopy("Copy").getId();

  // Open the temporary spreadsheet
  var copySs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(copyId);

  // Get the sheet
  var copySheet = copySs.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var values = sheet.getRange("A9:F9");

  var copyRange = copySheet.getRange("A9:F9");

  copyRange.setValues(values);

  //Convert Template File to PDF
  emailMe(copyId, email, name);
}

function emailMe(copyId, email, name) {
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");
  var subject = "Test";
  var body = "This is a test.";

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- In your script, I think that when `copyRange.setValues(values);` is run, an error occurs. Because `values` is a range. It's `var values = sheet.getRange("A9:F9");`.

  - I thought that you might want to retrieve the values of `A9:F9`.
- After modified above, in order to reflect `copyRange.setValues(values);` before the PDF is output, please use `SpreadsheetApp.flush();`.

#### Modified script :

From :

```
var values = sheet.getRange("A9:F9");
var copyRange = copySheet.getRange("A9:F9");
copyRange.setValues(values);
//Convert Template File to PDF
emailMe(copyId, email, name);
```

To :

```
var values = sheet.getRange("A9:F9").getValues(); // Modified
var copyRange = copySheet.getRange("A9:F9");
copyRange.setValues(values);
SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Added
//Convert Template File to PDF
emailMe(copyId, email, name);
```

#### References :

- [SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush())

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: The SpreadsheetApp.flush() command was what I was missing! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Robert Anthony Svec I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.